# Virtual Environment Module ( ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, python-requests, virtualenv

Hello I am having issues with adding the module "requests" to my virtual environment. I already did pip install requests but it states the requirement is already satisfied but when I got to run my program that depends on "requests" it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. I have already tried deleting and adding my virtual environment but that didn't work. Any help would be great, please see below screenshot of my terminal. [image: screenshot of terminal]

[image: 2nd image with using which pip]k.imgur.com/mpVVG.jpg

[image]

Comment: can you run `which pip` can share the output?  If you look at your response from `pip install requests` it's installing it in the base python installation, not your virtual environment.

Comment: @Kyle I just edited the image to show which pip...I think you might be right that its installing it in my global environment and not virtual...am I missing a step? I though that once I was in my virtual environment I just had to do pip install requests.

Comment: Can you list the files that are inside the bin directory of your virtual environment?

Comment: @Kyle just added another image....is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Can you try my answer listed below as a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your $PATH or environment variables are getting messed up somewhere.  As a work around, you can run the specific pip command from the inside of your virtualenv.  Let's say for example that my virtualenv is called venv_test and it's in my current directory. Make sure you already 'sourced' your virtual environment before running the following.

```
cd venv_test
cd bin
./pip install requests
```

It might help to recreate your virtualenv too in case something got switched around.  Let's say we have python3 installed along with the default python2.7 that comes with OSX, we can create a python3 specific virtual_env with the following.

```
mkvirtualenv --python=python3.6 python3_venv
source python3_venv/bin/activate
pip install requests
```

Comment: great thanks for your help! The workaround helped, but I also just recreated it as well since I think something in that path was messed up. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad we kind of got it working.  Hopefully someone else can comment on a possible permanent fix for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, make sure that the line at the beginning of the Python script invokes the interpreter set in the virtual environment by using, for example, `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Invoking the Python interpreter directly with `#!/usr/bin/python` ignores the virtual environment and would result in a `ModuleNotFoundError`. HTH.